# how to interpret this TensorBoard graph of loss value?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function

After the training i got this graph of loss value . When the loss become approximately smaller than 25,  at some point this value become instantaneously very big (150, 140).

Somebody suggested that the problem can be over fitting , but even after i tried different percentages of dropout (30%, 40% 60%) the problem remains.
[a graph of loss function during training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYvxw.png)

Comment: How large is your training dataset? Sometimes even with dropout we can be susceptible to overfitting if the training data are too sparse.

Comment: the data comes from monitoring of a SDN network and some servers performance, such as CPU and memory load. The data is generated in real time ,so, the dataset itself is big enough, but it is possible that many data points  is very similar to each other.